# Mouse sticks to top of screen when playing video

Tags: mouse, vlc

I'm pretty new to Linux/Ubuntu, so I sorry if my question is too vague.
The issue I'm having is that everytime I'm playing a videofile (I've tested with avi and mkv) my mouse is stuck to the top of my screen. I can move it down for maybe an inch when it goes back to the top.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You have not described your hardware.  Is there a touch pad as well as a mouse?  These can conflict at times and the touch pad has to be blacklisted.

Comment: Sorry, yes it's a laptop, so there is a touchpad. Which works fine, it's just the mouse connected to it that fails.

Comment: I don't know how, but it suddenly just works. Thanks for your help!